# Bixby: How to test Private Submission in Note 9

Tags: bixby

I saw this statement from Dev Guide: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/deploying.can-submission

[image]

I have Note 9. Can I use it for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment but once the CAN Marketplace is released (possibly sometime next year), you should be able to. The DevGuide page you referenced above is part of the documentation related to Working with the CAN Marketplace.

For now, you can test your capsule through the Simulator that comes with the IDE.